# How to remove all the attached events to an HTML element

Tags: jquery, html, events, detach

I would to know how can I remove all the attached events to an HTML element in jQuery. We suppose that we have the instruction below:

```
$('<div class="notification" style="bottom:'+ind+'px">Message envoyé '+i+'<span class="close">x</span></div>').fadeIn(1000,"linear").delay(5000).fadeOut(3000,"linear");
```

How can I remove the fadeIn, delay and fadeOut events which are attached to the html event without using on(), bind()....etc ??...In fact I tried with .off(), .unbind(), .die(), .undelegate() but it didn't work. Is there anyone who has an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those aren't events, those are jQuery functions. Events are click, mouseover, keyup, etc.

Comment: These aren't events: they are queued functions. Maybe `dequeue` would do the trick? http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/ It's not likely, though, as you would need to interrupt control flow before `fadeIn` was called.

Comment: those aren't events, they are added to the animation queue. so what about .stop()? http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: @ajm: I tried dequeue() method but when I mouseover the div there will be a fadeout directly, what I really would like is when I mouseover the div there will not be a fadeOut at all. do you have any idea how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to .stop the animation inside a hover... I don't have your html and css, but i created a [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xahor/1/edit). Sorry it took so long to get back to you regarding your question, I was setting up my dev environment.

```
// where msgEl is the new element you create
msgEl 
  .hover(function(){
    tmpl.stop(1,1).fadeIn(1);
  },function(){
    tmpl.stop(1,1).fadeIn(1);
  })
  .hide(0)
  .fadeIn(1000,"linear")
  .delay(5000)
  .fadeOut(3000,"linear");
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xahor/1/edit)

Comment: I tried that, but when I mouseover the div it disappears directly, what I really would like is when I mouseover the div there will not be a fadeOut.

Comment: ok i changed it to do the hover behavior, sorry it wasn't clear at first :)

Comment: in fact, this is my complete code: [link](http://jsbin.com/tawix/1/edit)...what shall I add to the line below to make it work correctly??:

var a = $('<div class="notification" style="bottom:'+ind+'px">Message envoyé '+i+'<span class="close">x</span></div>').fadeIn(1000,"linear").delay(5000).fadeOut(3000,"linear").hover(function(){},function(){});

Thanks in advance.

Comment: exactly, just add `$(this).stop(1,1).fadein(1)` inside the first hover callback. That stops the animation on hover and forces it to fade back in...